# How to show image programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to show image with text.

```
t_s.setText("You will be shown a picture like this"+R.drawable.myimage);
```

That's my code, but not work, it show not image, but number..

Comment: you want view to have background image

Answer (score 0):

```
t_s.setText("You will be shown a picture like this");
t_s.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

try these code if you nedd to set background to view

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a TextView and a ImageView separated.